# Can a critical process be made non-critical and then terminated?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-kernel

Are we able to change an already critical process to non critical using `RtlSetProcessIsCritical`, for example `svchost`, into being considered as not critical by Windows? If so, what would happen if we were to set an important process as non-critical and terminate it?

This isn't something I plan to test or really use, more of just a random thought as to what would happen if we could terminate a critical process without a blue screen.

Comment: I think it might be a bit like deliberately shooting yourself in the foot.  It's going to hurt and is unlikely to achieve very much.

Comment: What happens depends on the critical process and what it provides. Back in the day, I could tell you what each of the 22 processes running in the background on my computer did, at least in a general sense. I don't even try with the 229 of the little <expletive deleted>ers running on the box I have today. Couldn't even tell you which are considered critical.

Comment: And I think I should have added that processes are marked as critical for a reason.  `winlogon` is a case in point - if you kill it then you can't logon or (probably) logoff either.  And as for `svchost`, you have no idea how many services it is running unless you inspect it with something like Process Explorer so good luck killing any particular instance of that.  You might also find [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180216-00/?p=98035) of interest.  It will give you some insight into what a critical process actually _is_.

Comment: yes it would obviously cause damage or some sort of issue. thats why this question was just a thought and not something I was actually going to do.

Comment: I would say that was wise.  Windows blue screens can leave the registry in an inconsistent state and that can lead to all sorts of grief.  I once interrupted my system while it was booting.  Never again - I ended up having to reinstall.

Comment: It's like saying, "There's an electrical panel in the basement of my apartment building that says 'do not open'. What would happen if I opened it and cut all the wires?" Sounds like you already know the answer: "it would obviously cause damage or some sort of issue."

Comment: This sounds like a good thing to try out inside a VM :)

Answer (score 0):

In user-mode, no.

A kernel driver could flip a bit in the process structure but this is not a good idea.

If you want to try it just for fun, setup yourself to do kernel debugging and look at the `EPROCESS` of your target process.